# object initializer execution order

Tags: c#, .net, mono

C# 3 introduced object initializers.

```
var person = new Person () {
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
};
```

When I set multiple properties, they're assigned in the order listed, both in .NET and Mono. Is it only by luck, or is this by standard and can I rely on this behaviour ?

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495616/order-of-operations-using-object-initializer-syntax

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".