# C#: distinguish init accessors from set accessors in records using reflection

Tags: c#

I need to use reflection to check for non-writeable properties in C# positional records.

Here is a sample positional record:

```
record MyRecord(int MyProperty);
```

`MyProperty` is non-writeable as expected:

```
MyRecord myRecord = new(5);
Console.WriteLine(myRecord.MyProperty); // 5
//myRecord.MyProperty = 6; <-- yields compile time error as expected
```

However, reflection tells me this:

```
PropertyInfo pi = typeof(MyRecord).GetProperty("MyProperty");
Console.WriteLine(pi.CanWrite);     // True
MethodInfo mi = pi.GetSetMethod();  
Console.WriteLine(mi == null);      // False
Console.WriteLine(mi.IsPublic);     // True
```

So `MyProperty` appears to be public writeable. The problem seems to be the init accessor since

```
record MyRecord
{
    public int MyProperty { get; } = 5;
}
```

has `CanWrite` for `MyProperty` set to `false`, but this kind of record definition is not what I need.

So is there a means how to distinguish an init accessor from a set accessor in records using reflection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [`GetRequiredCustomModifiers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getrequiredcustommodifiers?view=net-5.0) on the `ReturnParameter` of the `Set` method. The type you're looking for is [`IsExternalInit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.isexternalinit?view=net-5.0)

```
var rec = typeof(MyRecord);
var prop = rec.GetProperty("MyProperty");
var setMethod = prop.GetSetMethod();
var mods = setMethod.ReturnParameter.GetRequiredCustomModifiers().Contains(typeof(IsExternalInit));
Console.WriteLine("Init: {0}", mods);
```

Comment: I've just tried that, and it returns an empty array. The `modreq` is applied to the set method, not the property itself, and I can't find a way of accessing those for a method...

Comment: @JonSkeet - Indeed. It's actually on the `ReturnParameter` of the `set` method, my mistake.

Comment: Aha... well spotted. (It's not hugely obvious from the IL, and I'm far from an IL expert, unfortunately.)

Comment: [Also documented here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43088). Clunky indeed.

Comment: Interesting how the documentation page for [`IsExternalInit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.isexternalinit?view=net-5.0) says "This class should not be used by developers in source code", but it's the only way for developers to detect init properties...

Comment: The *class* should indeed arguably not be used. Modreqs only check for the full name of the type, so the check should probably do that as well. Assuming `IsExternalInit` is available as a type at the point of reflection is technically not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the property MyProperty CanWrite = false you can achieve this by this doing the following:

```
  record MyRecord {
      public int MyProperty { get; }
      
      public MyRecord(int myProperty) {
          MyProperty = myProperty;
      }
```

}

If you look at the IL generated code for record MyRecord(int MyProperty); you'll notice this:

```
public int MyProperty
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    get
    {
        return <MyProperty>k__BackingField;
    }
    [CompilerGenerated]
    init // <- what's being generated
    {
        <MyProperty>k__BackingField = value;
    }
}
```